"We are certainly not what you would call close friends." — If "what" refers to "we", then we must use "who" instead. Why is "what" correct here?
thefreedictionary.com:
(1) We are only acquainted with each other. We are certainly not what you would call close friends.
As far as I understand, the word "what" refers to people here, not to things. But I've always thought we can't use "what" in such cases and we must use "who" instead.
Why is it correct to use "what" in (1)?
Why is it correct to use "what" when we refer to someone [as in (1)]?

my variant:
(2) We are only acquainted with each other. We are certainly not who you would call close friends.
What's the difference between (1) and (2)?

Your who version is not idiomatic. The original (what) version is. The collocation is so strong a convention that its use regarding people versus things is utterly accepted and acceptable. One could read it as a shortening of an example of what.

What doesn't refer to the people, it refers to the relationship of being 'close friends'.


We are only acquainted with each other.  We are certainly not what you would call close friends.

I add to what @Kate Bunting said.
The second sentence roughly means Our relationship is certainly not what you would call close friends'.
What has our relationship as antecedent.
As Paul pointed out too, we are and what collocate in lots of constructions.  Examples of we are what we include we are what we eat (or ate), we are what we wear, we are what we pretend to be, and so on.
Hence the OP's original quote is fine.
